# Using merge sort to remove duplicate entries in array

Tags: java, arrays, mergesort, repeat

I checked questions which are related to my issue before posting this question, but couldn't find anything useful. I'm trying to modify the merge sort algorithm to delete duplicate entries in an array of integers. Unfortunately, the only result I obtained is an ordered array where the duplicate entries are replaced by zeros.

```
public static int[] mergeSort(int[] array, int left, int right){
     int[] sortedArray = null;
     if(left == right){
         sortedArray = new int[1];
         sortedArray[0] = array[left];
         return sortedArray;
         }

     int mid = (left+right)/2;
     int[] subA = mergeSort(array, left, mid);
     int[] subB = mergeSort(array, mid+1, right);
     sortedArray = merge(subA, subB);
     return sortedArray;
 }

 private static int[] merge(int[] subA, int[]subB){
     int[] mergedArray = new int[subA.length+subB.length];
     int i, j, k;
     i = 0;
     j = 0;
     k = 0;

     while(i < subA.length && j < subB.length){
         if(subA[i] < subB[j]){
             mergedArray[k] = subA[i];
             i++;
         }
         else if(subA[i] > subB[j]){
             mergedArray[k] = subB[j];
             j++;
         }
         //if the two elements are equal
         else{
             mergedArray[k] = subA[i];
             i++;
             j++;
         }
         k++;
     }

     if(j >= subB.length){
         while(i < subA.length){
             mergedArray[k] = subA[i];
             i++;
             k++;
         }
     }
     else{
         while(j < subB.length){
             mergedArray[k] = subB[j];
             j++;
             k++;
         }
     }

     return mergedArray;
 }
```

Here is the output of the code above:

[image: Output:]

Am I missing some fundamental point? Is there any effective way to modify this code in order to obtain an array of unique elements without this zero repetition?

Comment: Why not just create a new array where you don't write the 0 values into it? Just keep a counter of how many unique elements you detect and then you will also know how big your new array has to be at the end.

Comment: I also thought about something like this, unfortunately it's not excluded the case in which one or more zeros are elements of the initial array, and it would be impossible to distinguish the "right" zeros from the "wrong" ones.

Comment: But you should only retain one zero anyway, right? So what if after sort is done you copy contents into a new array and only copy a zero if element before it is negative or border, and element after it is positive or border? Although that still requires you to keep track of whether a zero was in original array or not, but this can also be done on the first pass.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
HashSet<T> uniqueElems = new HashSet<>(yourArrayList);
```

And if you wanted back to array

```
yourArrayList = new ArrayList<>(uniqueElems);
```

assuming your equals() method for the element is defined correctly

Answer (score 0):

First of all using array instead of ArrayList or other Collection is just a hard way to make that kind of code successful.
Anyways here is how to solve this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i : mergedArray)
       list.add(i);
```

And now the return statement will look like this:

```
return list.stream().distinct().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
```

**distinct()** - removes all duplicates.

**mapToInt(i -> i).toArray()** - makes ArrayList just an array again.